# how to test connections of all replication servers in node.js sequelize library

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I did configuration of replication database but when i test it using authenticate method, only return a message from one read server even though i used two read servers and one write server.

here is my configuration

```
replication : {
  read: [
    { host:'127.0.0.1', username:'repl1', password:'' },
    { host:'127.0.0.1', username:'repl2', password:'' }
  ],
  write: { host: '127.0.0.1', username: 'master', password: '' }
}
```

is there a way to test connections of all replication hosts?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You specified the same `host` twice in your `read` array. You should use two different hosts, or specify 2 different `port` properties for the same host.

*Also, you have a typo: `'repl2` should be `'repl2'`.*

Comment: thanks for comments. sorry for bad typo. i did change one of host at read hosts but i got message from database only one (first one of read array). it seems it did not connect all of hosts